# Eclipse does not expand field when rendered as PDF

Tags: eclipse, pdf, birt, birt-emitter

I have an Eclipse report with a grid.  When it renders as HTML, the grid expands vertically to show all data within it.

However, when I try to print it as a PDF, the grid stays the original size and cuts off the print.

Any ideas of what I am missing?

Rendered as HTML: [image]

Rendered as PDF: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, PDF output is less permissive with styling errors than HTML. In this case you probably have set a height property on table rows or on detail cells, and BIRT tries to render accurately what it is asked.

As you can see in [this example](http://www.visioneo.org/metadata-report?birt_indicator=AG.LND.FRST.K2), the PDF output won't limit by its own the table fields if the height property is not set, whatever the size of fields is.

Comment: That was perfect!  Somehow I had inadvertently gotten height statments into my XML file and that was throwing the PDF's off. Thank you very much!